# How can I dynamically move/resize a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing an alert system that will show messages 'a la' Messenger, and I want them to move or resize to make them appear.

How can I do this without having to do this:

```
do
{
this.prop += 1;
} while (this. prop  = destination);
```

Comment: I don't understand the connection between that bit of code and the functionality that you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to avoid using a tight loop to change the coordinates and/or size of a window?

Comment: @Adam Crossland - yep, I want to 'animate' the form without doing those nasty loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) component and call the form's [`SetBounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0tayb1b.aspx) method in the timer's `Tick` event.

Answer (score 0):

set `form.size` property to change size, `form.position` to change position

Answer (score 0):

You need a frame rate independent interpolator.

Take a look at: [Frame Rate Independent interpolation](http://books.google.com/books?id=hiBFUv_FT0wC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=easeout+interpolation&source=bl&ots=OBhFKzw8-e&sig=2jbIws4uYaxfsqY9o4IvJBKWWks&hl=en&ei=djJPS6mbFInEsQPWrMGBCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CBAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=&f=false). Basically, the idea is that you compute what your current position should be based upon the expected animation time and how long you've been animating... This means that the animation will take the same amount of time to go from point a to point b on any hardware.

Of course, you'll need to position the form with the values coming out of this, but thats the easy part!